# Getting the default value (text) of an <input> element with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wonder about how I can use selenium webdriver to find the default text of an  element ?
In the browser, the input field displays a default value: 'Project 1', but I cannot get this text through the method getText() of this WebElement.

```
<input class="title viewData" id="sprojectName" maxlength="255" name="projectName" type="text" projectinfo="1">
```

Comment: Is there any `placeholder` attribute that you are missing in your html?

Comment: Hi Nitin, it is the full html tag for that input.

Answer (score 2):

`getText()` returns "the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace." You need something like `getAttribute("value")` or `getAttribute("placeholder")`.

Answer (score 2):

The getText() method is for retrieving a text node between element tags for example:

Eg:

```
<p>New</p>
```

But usually the value in the text box is saved to "value" attribute. So the below statement will work:

```
findElement(By.id("ElementID")).getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I will try to see if getAttribute("value") work. In the meantime, I have solved the problem using JavaScript executor:

```
String jsStatement = "return document.getElementById('" + elementId + "')." + "value" + ";";
JavascriptExecutor js = null;
if (session instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)session;
}
return (String) js.executeScript(jsStatement);
```